# jQuery - CSS class being applied but not taking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm applying a CSS class using `.addClass` when a tab is selected and it is also adding the class to the parents parent tab. The class is being added but the CSS doesn't seem to be taking effect of the parents parent class (apologies if that sounds awkward).

CSS:

```
.selectedTab{
  color:#234 !important;
  background-color:white !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Visit Northern Ireland</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="js/common.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/armagh.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="centeredPane">
    <nav>
      <ul id="css-tabs">
        <li><a href="#" class="contentLinks selectedTab" name="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="activities">Activities</a>
          <div class="subnav" id="activitiesLink">
            <a href="#" name="armagh" class="contentLinks">Co. Armagh</a>
            <a href="#" name="antrim" class="contentLinks">Co. Antrim</a>
            <a href="#" name="down" class="contentLinks">Co. Down</a>
            <a href="#" name="fermanagh" class="contentLinks">Co. Fermanagh</a>
            <a href="#" name="londonderry" class="contentLinks">Co. Londonderry</a>
            <a href="#" name="tryone" class="contentLinks">Co. Tyrone</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" name="restaurants">Restaurants</a>
          <div class="subnav" id="restaurantLink">
            <a href="#" name="indian" class="contentLinks">Indian</a>
            <a href="#" name="tapas" class="contentLinks">Tapas</a>
            <a href="#" name="american" class="contentLinks">American</a>
            <a href="#" name="italian" class="contentLinks">Italian</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="contentLinks" name="game">Game</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content" id="home">home</div>
    <div class="content" id="armagh">armagh</div>
    <div class="content" id="antrim">antrim</div>
    <div class="content" id="down">down</div>
    <div class="content" id="fermanagh">fermanagh</div>
    <div class="content" id="londonderry">londonderry</div>
    <div class="content" id="tryone">tyrone</div>
    <div class="content" id="indian">indian</div>
    <div class="content" id="tapas">tapas</div>
    <div class="content" id="american">american</div>
    <div class="content" id="italian">italian</div>
    <div class="content" id="game">game</div>
    <footer>For more information visit <a href="http://www.discovernorthernireland.com/" target="_blank">Discover Northern Ireland</a></footer>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.contentLinks').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selectedTab");
  $('a').not(this).removeClass("selectedTab");
  //var is_element_li = $(this).parent().parent().get(0).tagName.is("li");
  var is_element_li = $(this).parent().parent().is("li");
  if(is_element_li){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selectedTab");
  }
  var nameAttribute = $(this).attr('name');
  nameAttribute = "#"+ nameAttribute;
  $(nameAttribute).show();  
  $('div.content').not(nameAttribute).hide();
});
```

How can I get the style to apply?

Comment: How/where have you checked that the class is being added?

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a Fiddle?

Comment: No, it doesn't; I get a hash-change and then this: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A90Dz.png); incidentally, if you're using `parent().parent()` stop that, and use `closest(selectorString)` instead.

Comment: It seems to take effect .. is this wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GEDf6/

Comment: In the example you linked to, the styles for the `a` are not changed because only the `li` gets the new class, but the `a` styles supersede them.

Comment: the anchor is not the parent().parent(), the li is, you need to add anohter children('a') on there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `selectedTab` class to your anchor element, instead of the the `li` element:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children("a").addClass("selectedTab");
```

Comment: That somewhat worked, I've updated the code on the live link, if you click the "Game" tab you'll see that it now changes the background behind the tabs white which is not what I want.

Comment: It looks like you've somehow added the `selectedTab` class to the `ul`, which is causing it to display that way. Please double-check your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgot to change my code just after the `if` statement.